# Выполнить GET сразу после POST запроса

Tags: post, php, запрос, get

Нужно при нажатии по кнопке выполнить сперва ПОСТ, а потом ГЕТ запрос. Может есть способ выполнить гет в посте? Соль в том, что страницы выполнения разные. Гет должен выполниться на стороннем сервере, а пост я выполняю у себя.

Вот эти два запроса:

```
<form method="GET" action="/outedget">
<input type="hidden" name="m_1" value="1234">
<input type="submit" name="m_process" value="send" /> // Эту кнопку можно убрать
</form>

<form id="forma" action="/outmy" method="POST">
<input id="po" type="text" name="po"></center>
<input id="ooo" type="hidden" name="ooo" value="1">
</form>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('ooo').value=1;with(document.getElementById('forma')){ submit(); }">GO</a> // Тыкать будем по этой кнопе
```

Comment: 1. Вангую неправильную архитектуру, требуются подробности задачи.
2. Любой запрос "по умолчанию" - это GET, что мешает просто перенаправить пользователя?
3. Вангую, что и пользователь тут на самом деле ни при чем, а надо курлом тянуть.

Comment: Я дал формы, которые нужно слить в одну или выполнить по очереди. При отправке Пост формы нужно записать кое-какие значения в бд, а потом выполнить Гет.

Comment: ajax для этого придуман.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: @eicto, внешний хост. Что, правда, не запрещает создать что-нибудь типа `<img src="http://host.com/omg.php?val1=noway"/>`.  
@Rammsteinik, я уже написал оптимальное решение в пункте два. Не хотите раскрывать подробности - могу дать только такой ответ. Если вам нужно без перезагрузки страницы - то это надо было все-таки указать, сначала аяксом выполняем одну форму, потом аяксом или хаком вторую.

Comment: хотя... если вам не надо ответ от GET обрабатывать, то просто положите копию формы в iframe  и нажмите там эту кнопку, а POST отправьте из самой формы. писать это что-то много, поищите сами как клонировать ноды и как обращаться к iframe, (еще непонятно ответ от какого сервера всё таки нужен на экране - от того кому POST или кому GET ? )

Comment: на экране нужен последний - Гет

Comment: тогда гуглите ajax.